# Alarm application using the maximum possible volume level

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, sound-volume, alarm

The iPhone's alarm shares its volume with the ringer, and I don't want the ringer volume to be too loud. I am looking for an alarm application for iPhone using the maximum possible volume level.

Ideally, it would gradually increase the volume till the maximum possible volume level. If it needs the iOS to be jailbroken, that's fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Wake Alarm Clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wake-alarm-clock/id616764635?mt=8) app does exactly what you want. No jailbreak required, progressive increase of volume up to the maximum. But, I'm using it because there is a setting that forces you to shake your phone to stop the alarm, and you are awaken almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Safe Alarm 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3lf6bv/upcoming_safe_alarm_2_the_ultimate_alarm_tweak/) application. It works on all iPhones and iPads with iOS 7, 8 and 9.

Per Alarm Features:

- Volume Level
- Song Fade-in with custom time
- Custom Vibration on Silent and Ring Mode
- Snooze Time
- Auto Dismiss Alarms in a predefined time (Stop or Snooze)
- Math Equation to disable alarm with 4 difficulties

Global Features:

- All Per Alarm Features can be default to whatever you want
- Custom Sleep Button Action ( Stop, Snooze or No Action )
- Swipe to Delete Alarms
- Button to Toggle All Alarms
- Open Clock on Alarms Tab on Control Center
- Disable Touch ID unlock when Alarm Triggers
- Stop Alarm from LockScreen instead of only Snoozing
- Show Remaining time until Alarm fires directly on the clock app
- Activator Gestures: Stop the Alarm, Snooze the Alarm, Turn On All Alarms and Turn Off All Alarms

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]